# Soft keys enabled covers shortcuts at Lockscreen in Redmi 1s MIUI 8 [Root]

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, lock-screens, softkey

[image]

I have rooted my Redmi 1s KitKat version, and enabled soft keys ( by `editing build.prop, qemu.hw.mainkeys=0` ). The shortcut keys ( lock screen shortcut, such as contacts and camera on the left and right of screen on bottom respectively ) are not visible at lockscreen, it is covered by black portion of softkeys ( soft keys are also not visible).

- How to disable soft keys at lockscreen(black portion)?.
- Also, the screen size is reduced (about 0.7 cm is covered by black portion of soft keys),is it possible to change the background of soft keys transparent, and to make android view to fullscreen?

Comment: @beeshyams added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using apps like [GMD Full Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmd.immersive) to hide softkeys when not in use (aka Immersive Mode). Or better, just ditch the navbar and use [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150) for the same effect (and more).

As for the lockscreen, since no Xiaomi devices inherently have softkeys, they designed the UI without it in mind, therefore parts of the UI won't adapt to it without undergoing modifications.